# Python pip install from wheel

Tags: python, pip, windows-server-2008, python-wheel

When I'm trying to install whl package on my Windows Server 2008 without the Internet, I get the error:

```
Processing f:\установки\flask_cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status
=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.con
nection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000A87AD94B88>, 'Connection to py
pi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/flask/
```

Comment: Can you please post the command you ran?

Comment: Did you try: `pip install flask_cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl`?

Comment: yes, i'm trying ```pip install flask_cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl``` 
from folder f:\установки